# Is it possible to create 'outlined' versions of vector artwork in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, vector-graphics

I am trying to create a user interface for a game I'm working on, that allows the user to build towers. The tower layers are made of vector artwork within MovieClips that can be modified by the player.

When the player selects a layer to modify, I'd like to present the current artwork in a 'blueprints' style screen, that will ignore all colour data and present the vector artwork as white outlined shapes, on a blueprint style background.

My question then is, what's the best way to accomplish this? Can I somehow access the vector data in my artwork and switch it programatically to white lines and transparent fills? Or is it possible some other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that look with a simple [GlowFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) that has:

1. Low blur value and high strength to fake the stroke
2. The 'knockout' option set to true, so the fill becomes transparent.

e.g.

```
yourMovieClip.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x000099,1,4,4,100,1,false,true)];
```

Feel free to play with the glow and strength values to get the look you want.

Comment: I experimented with filters, but this only picks out the outline around the shape, whereas I'd need to highlight things within the shape too. For example, some of the artwork has windows on, which I'd also like to pick out if I can.

Answer (score 0):

If your I think that what you're looking for could be achieved by using BitmapData. You could load your MovieClip into a BitmapData and read the contents pixel by pixel. You can find edges by reading the single pixel and comparing it with the last pixel. This obviously works just with black and white images